# Eliminating results < 6 months from one field while not affecting others

Tags: sql

I'm populating a webstore, but I'm not permitted to list certain items from one manufacturer in accordance to release dates. I'm stuck as to how to code this one manufacturer while not affecting the other items.

I've tried CASE WHEN, but it's not quite doing the trick. I might be doing it incorrectly?

```
SELECT sku, description, quantity_available, manufacturer
FROM test_db
WHERE quantity_available > 0
AND manufacturer = 'inquestion' 
  LIKE CASE WHEN release_date > dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What does this mean:  "I'm not permitted to list certain items from one manufacturer in accordance to release dates."?

Comment: Sure - I have one brand of item that is not permitted to be listed until it's been on the market for 6 months.

At the moment, without the barrier of the 6 month issue, I can return all results properly. I just need to filter the results from one manufacturer to release date > 6 months from today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the release date condition to apply to only one manufacturer, then you can use boolean logic:

```
WHERE quantity_available > 0 AND
      (manufacturer <> 'inquestion' OR
       release_date > dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
      )
```

You might find an alternative phrasing simpler to follow:

```
WHERE quantity_available > 0 AND
      NOT (manufacturer = 'inquestion' AND
           release_date < dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
          )
```

Comment: This is very close. It's eliminated all of the results that I want, but if I remove the NOT in your second phrasing it shows all items that I need to add to my original query (but eliminates all other items from other manufacturers)

Comment: @GraemeMartin . . . Both of these should keep all the other manufacturers.  Are you sure the parentheses are correct?

Comment: Oh god. There's not enough coffee in the world. Thank you. Solved!

Answer (score 0):

One way is using a union. Something like:

```
SELECT sku, description, quantity_available, manufacturer
FROM test_db
WHERE quantity_available > 0 AND manufacturer <> 'inquestion'
UNION ALL
SELECT sku, description, quantity_available, manufacturer
FROM test_db
WHERE quantity_available > 0
  AND manufacturer = 'inquestion'
  AND release_date > dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
```